# Crystal-Report Error: "@RecordSelection - This field name is not known" - but all fields are okay

Tags: crystal-reports

Does anybody know what this error message means, when I go to "Report->Check Dependencies":

```
"Formulas: @RecordSelection - This field name is not known. [filename]"
```

I get this Error 62-times for an report with 2 Subreports. If i doubleclick any of them it opens the Formular Workshop with the "Record Selection" of any of the reports (main or sub).

But the big question is: if I save the Formular Workshop it does not throw an error. If a fieldname is wrong it would say:

```
"There is an error in this formula. Do you want to save it anyway?"
```

The formulars are very simple, kind of:

```
 {Table.Field} = {?Parameter}
```

Even if i delete the Formular, i get the same 62 errors...

Has anybody seen such behavior?

The problem is, i can not compile my asp.net website with these reports in it, bec. it throws an error:

```
"Unable to Load Report"
```

CR Version: 13.0.2 for Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, nvm.

I was unable to find the problem - but i rebuild the report field by field and the exact same DB-setting and now its working...